# How to make 'pretty urls' work in php hosted in IIS?

Tags: php, iis

Is there some way I can use URLs like:

*http://www.blog.com/team-spirit/*

instead of

*http://www.blog.com/?p=122*

in a Windows hosted PHP server?

Comment: After reading question and answers...i have a question can we use `.htaccess` for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it with WordPress on IIS 6.0

http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/02/url-rewriter-reverse-proxy-iis-wordpress/

However it all depends on what version of IIS you are using.  If you are lucky enough to use IIS 7.0 you don't really have to worry about pretty urls because everything is supported out of the box.  However if you are using IIS 6.0 you are going to have to use a rewriter and some rules to force the IISness out of IIS.

Answer (score 3):

[Isapi Rewrite Filter on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) - actively developed, free ("DonationWare"), open source.

Answer (score 1):

Use the official [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)

Answer (score 0):

We use the free version of [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).  It uses similar syntax to mod_rewrite, so if you're familiar with that you may have an easier time getting started.

There used to be a (syntax-compatible) port of mod_rewrite for IIS, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Setting Up .NET to Process All Requests
Setup your frontend server to process everything through the .NET framework.

Open IIS and right-click on the website and select Properties.
Click the Configuration button under Application Settings section
Click the Insert... button to create a new wildcard mapping
Set the executable textbox to aspnet_isapi.dll file location. for .net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5: C:WindowsMicrosoft.NETFrameworkv2.0.50727aspnet_isapi.dll
Make sure the checkbox Verify that file exists is not checked.
Press OK to confirm and close all the windows.
Step 2 - Install PHP/WordPress
Just follow this article on IIS.NET for installing PHP/WordPress on IIS 6.0. You may also want to install FastCGI, I recommend this, but it is optional.

Step 3 - Setting Up the URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy Rules
The criteria for the requests are put inside the URL Rewriter Rules files. But before the proxy request is made, I must check to make sure the file being requested doesn't already exist on the frontend server. If it does exist on the frontend server I don't want to make a reverse proxy request. The following is the code used to do that.

```
# any file that exists just return it  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
```

Then after I check to make sure the file doesn't exist on the frontend server I make the request to the backend using the following rules.

https://nickberardi.com/url-rewriter-reverse-proxy-iis-wordpress/